# Sounds error (MonoGame)

Tags: c#, audio, directx, monogame

I am using the **Window Project** (in MonoGame 3.2)  which is using **DirectX** instead OpenGL.
If I run a game, so its show me:

> `"Could not load wind asset as a non-content file"`

I think, that is **no problem with my code** (If I use project, which is use OpenGL with the **same code**, so the sound load and **everything working perfect) but in DirectX is not working.**

Of course, that "wind" in output is set to "copy always" and "content". I used **format wav, wma, mp3, ogg** and if I use **xnb**, so it show

> "HRESULT: [0x80070002]. System cannot find a file"

**I am sure**, that **path** to sound **is correct.**

I dont know where is the problem. I am searching for the solving this problem two days, but still not with success. Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: Can you show the code you use to load the content? And with monogame the only format you can use is xnb. Don't forget to do not add the extension in your path string.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault
For example I create a new project. I think, that code is good.
My all project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96290835/GameName1.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For audio being called as the Song class, make sure to use WMA on Windows/WP8 and put the .wma and/or .xnb files in the same folder. Songs need to be WMA and sound effects should be 16bit WAV files. Try updating your question to include code snippets of your calls.

Comment: I have the same issue in windows. I'm sure the sounds files are OK since I copied them from an official monogame example. The sounds also work in Xamarin on Mac. But VS keeps saying it cannot load the files.